# Magento2 handling of downloadable product filetypes

Tags: magento2, downloadable

If I offer downloadable products on Magento2, some of them are corrupted after download, I cannot open them. It sais things like "this zip

Working fine: PDF, EPUB

Corrupted file after download: ZIP, MOBI.

I have not tried other filetypes. Any idea how to fix that?

Magento 2.3.5-p1, PHP7.3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: I had empty lines in the beginning of my `registration.php` of my custom theme before the start of the opening `<?php` tag.

Outch.